# mlr3proba surv.xgboost is not producing distr output + documentation link unstable

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr3

```
R version  used: 3.6.3, mlr3 version: 0.4.0-9000, mlr3proba version: 0.1.6.9000 and xgboost version: 0.90.0.2 (as stated on Rstudio package manager)
```

Unfortunately, when applying `surv.xgboost` for training and prediction, no `distr` output is produced as stated in the documentation: https://mlr3proba.mlr-org.com/reference/LearnerSurvXgboost.html, only `crank` and `lp` outputs are produced.

Also please note that the documentation link above is also unstable as it sometimes links to a new `mlr3proba` version 0.2.0 throwing a 404 error while other times it works and shows documentation notes for `surv.xgboost` as per `mlr3proba` 0.1.6.

Please let me know if you would like me to provide any further details concerning the issue. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You have a better chance of someone being able to help if you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/12400385) and show the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi thanks for using mlr3proba! Good spot on the documentation problem, I will get that fixed asap. xgboost does not natively predict `distr`, this is a mistake in the documentation. You can check this with `LearnerSurvXgboost$new()$predict_types`. However it is easy to get a distribution prediction:

```
library(mlr3); library(mlr3proba); library(mlr3pipelines)
learn = distrcompositor(lrn("surv.xgboost"), estimator = "kaplan", form = "ph")
```

You could change the `form` and `estimator` arguments though as xgboost assumes a PH form these are the most sensible options.

Let me know if the code chunk doesn't work for some reason, and if it does please mark as answered :)

Raphael

Comment: Dear Raphael thank you so much for your response, it seems to work in producing the distribution. However when deploying the distrcompose object the following error occurs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149750/mlr3-distrcompose-cdf-subscript-out-of-bounds